# How to discard changes in hibernate/JPA after Exception occur?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

how can I discard changes after Exception? I want to save recordB even when recordA failed to save.

```
//The transaction comes from else where, cannot modify it
@Transactional
void updateRecord{
    Record recordA = repository.findById(ida);
    Record recordB = repository.findById(idb);
    recordA.setXXX();
    recordB.setXXX();
    try {
        repository.saveAndFlush(recordA);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        if (exp instanceof DataIntegrityViolationException) {
            entityManager.detach(recordA);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(exp);
        }
    }
    repository.saveAndFlush(recordB);//got exception cause recordA still engaged
}
```

Comment: Have you tried remove @Transactional annotation?

Comment: @HưngChu can't, actually the transaction is not initial by my method

Comment: Have you tried  @Transactional(noRollbackFor=Exception.class) ? Hope this link helpful to you   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887675/continue-with-transaction-after-exception-jpa

Comment: @Mansi the transaction is not initial by me, so I can do nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not be done in same transaction.

1: need to set globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure = true

2: start an new transaction with proper propagation, do everything and rollback within that transaction